# Can I give a staff user delete access without change access?

Tags: django

I manage a django-1.6 application where I want to give a staff user access to delete instances of a specific model through the `/django` interface without giving that staff user access to change instances of that model.

For each model there are three permissions that can be granted individually `add`, `change`, and `delete`. So I tried to grant the staff user only the `delete` permission and none of the other two.

This did not achieve the desired result. The staff user can now see the name of the model in the overview, but it is not a link. So though this staff user has been granted `delete` permission he is unable to get to the page where he would find the instance to delete.

Is there any way in django-1.6 that a staff user can delete an instance of a model without also being granted `change` permission?

Comment: Umm.... exactly what django are you referring to?

Comment: @MichaelHampton https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/